# SAPUI5: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sapui5, undefined, wizard, sap-web-ide

What are the possible errors to get this error message?

[image]

I tried to google but it says it happens in the javascript file where the getelementbyid returns null. But I checked all the element ids and they are correct... I am thinking it could be some errors regarding to the wizard section in xml.

Comment: Please share the relevant bits of code.

Comment: @TimoSta sry I am not allowed to because it is work code. But I can tell you that I use the SAPUI5 Wizard template in the code.

Comment: Is this issue still reproducible?

Answer (score 1):

The most fundamental cause of this error is when Javascript encounters a statement attempting to read a property through an array index that doesn't exist, eg 'someArray[0].someProperty' would throw such an error if nothing exits at array index 0 of 'someArray'.

A very typical situation in which this arises is when a function is called that normally returns an array and the code assumes the 0 index exists; this often happens in jQuery calls where so many of those selector-type functions return an array of values, and the expectation/assumption is that the desired action is to be taken against the first element (index 0).